# Intent url for android app is not working

Tags: android, react-native, android-intent, deep-linking

I am a noob in Android development. I am using `com.testApp://challenge/1` for my application. I added below code in `AndroidManifest.xml` file but it's not working.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="com.testApp" android:host="challenge"/>
</intent-filter>
```

I am not sure what is going wrong. Is it wrong `<data>` tag or wrong URL?

Comment: read this article for better understanding https://medium.com/@muratcanbur/intro-to-deep-linking-on-android-1b9fe9e38abd

Comment: @PayamKokabi I went through a couple of articles and understood as well but my first question is `com.testApp://challenge/1` is a valid intent URI?. There was no mention what is the format of scheme

Comment: Can you just try by changing testApp://challenge/1 and <data android:scheme="testApp" android:host="challenge"/>

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me:-

```
    <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    <data android:scheme="testApp" android:host="challenge" 
 android:pathPattern=".*" />
                </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Bhaskar Dabhi android:scheme can be anything you want as long as you pass the same Url